# Relation between Lie group projective representations and representations of its universal cover

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Given a Lie group $G$, and its universal cover $\tilde{G}$, under what conditions are the projective (linear) representations of $G$ and the representations of $\tilde{G}$ in a one-to-one correspondance?

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel of the universal cover is contained in the center, then every irreducible ordinary rep of its universal cover can induce a projective rep of itself. This is due to Schur’s lemma.

But some entry of Wikipedia [Representation of a Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) asserts that the we can always induce that. I don’t know how to prove it or whether it is true.

Conversely it is also true if we suppose G to be connected, as also asserted in the above link. Also there is another Wikipedia link: [Projective representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation)